# Does Feign retry require some sort of configuration?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I just tried to do a attempted a seamless upgrade of a service in a test setup. The service is being accessed by a Feign client. And naively I was under the impression that with multiple instances available of the service, the client would retry another instance if it failed to connect to one.

That, however, did not happen. But I cannot find any mention of how Feign in Spring Cloud is supposed to be configured to do this? Although I have seen mentions of it supporting it (as opposed to using RestTemplate where you would use something like Spring Retry?)

Comment: feign in and of itself doesn't do retry.  Are you using ribbon?

Comment: Spring Retry would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ribbon you can set properties similar to the following (substituting "localapp" for your serviceid):

```
localapp.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=5
localapp.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=5
localapp.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
```

Comment: Yes I am using Ribbon. But I am still not 100% on where exactly the responsibility domains lie. Setting it for each service seems like a lot of configuration though. Is there a way to set it a default for all users?

Comment: you can drop the service part, so just `ribbon.*`

Comment: Really? Well that's a nice tidbit I wasn't aware of.

Comment: yup, that's how netflix does the defaults.

Comment: Where is the documentation for any of these properties ?

Comment: The netflix/ribbon wiki and http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR5/#_retrying_failed_requests

Comment: Which errors will be retried? all errors? if the called service return 4XX status, this will also be retried? can i have control over it based on the response?

Comment: Exceptions are retried. There is a `decoded404` flag that will make it not produce an error.

Comment: @spencergibb, looks like IOExceptions will be retried.. i debugged it and looks like both 400 and 404 are returned as normal response

Comment: @Roi Ezra use ribbon.retryableStatusCodes to choose the status codes for which you wish to retry

Answer (score 2):

ps underneath Feign has a Retryer interface, which was made to support things like Ribbon.

https://github.com/Netflix/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Retryer.java

Comment: Adrian, how the feign retyer and the ribbon retry mechnism work together? is there any example or docs about it

Answer (score 1):

see if property works - OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true

You can refer application -> 
https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-sandbox/blob/master/spring-cloud-sandbox-sample-frontend/src/main/resources/application.yml

Spencer was quick...was late by few minutes :-)