# Feign client and Spring retry

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, spring-retry

I have a restful service calling an external service using Spring Cloud Feign client

```
@FeignClient(name = "external-service", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface ServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/payments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addPayment(@Valid @RequestBody AddPaymentRequest addPaymentRequest);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/payments/{paymentId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ChangePaymentStatusResponse updatePaymentStatus(@PathVariable("paymentId") String paymentId,
            @Valid @RequestBody PaymentStatusUpdateRequest paymentStatusUpdateRequest);

}
```

I noticed the following failure 3-4 times in the last 3 months in my log file:

> json.ERROR_RESPONSE_BODY:Connection refused executing POST
>   http://external-service/external/payments json.message:Send Payment
>   Add Payment Failure For other reason: {ERROR_RESPONSE_BODY=Connection
>   refused executing POST http://external-service/external/payments,
>   EVENT=ADD_PAYMENT_FAILURE, TRANSACTION_ID=XXXXXXX} {}
>   json.EVENT:ADD_PAYMENT_FAILURE
>   json.stack_trace:feign.RetryableException: Connection refused
>   executing POST http://external-service/external/payments at
>   feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67) at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:104)
>   at
>   feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
>   at
>   feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)

Is it possible to add Spring Retry on a Feign client.
What I wanted to annotate the `addPayment` operation with

```
@Retryable(value = {feign.RetryableException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000, multiplier=2))
```

But this is not possible, what other options do I have?

Comment: According to the docs it is possible...https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_retrying-failed-requests.html

I can't get it working though.

Comment: Currently (end of 2023) it's possible to configure this without any additional effort.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add a `Retryer` in the `FeignClientConfig`

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return new Custom();
    }

}

class Custom implements Retryer {

    private final int maxAttempts;
    private final long backoff;
    int attempt;

    public Custom() {
        this(2000, 3);
    }

    public Custom(long backoff, int maxAttempts) {
        this.backoff = backoff;
        this.maxAttempts = maxAttempts;
        this.attempt = 1;
    }

    public void continueOrPropagate(RetryableException e) {
        if (attempt++ >= maxAttempts) {
            throw e;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(backoff);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Retryer clone() {
        return new Custom(backoff, maxAttempts);
    }
}
```

Updated with sample `Retryer` example config based on the `Retryer.Default`.

Comment: Can you point to the code sample showing custom Retryer? How to configure retry only for feign.RetryableException and max attempt = 3 and  backoff period 2 sec between retries

Comment: You can just implement your own Retryer

Comment: In this scenario, how many times the external API will be invoked inclding the retries ? Is it like Call-1 (Normal call in the beginning) + Call-2 (retry-1) +  Call-3 (retry-2) +  Call-4 (retry-3)  
OR
 is it like Call-1 (Normal call in the beginning) + Call-2 (retry-1) +  Call-3 (retry-2)

Comment: Why continueOrPropagate method is not getting called?

Answer (score 4):

Just new a contructor `Default`

```
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public Retryer retryer() {
        return new Retryer.Default(100, 2000, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ribbon you can set properties, you can use below properties for retry:

```
myapp.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=5
myapp.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=5
myapp.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
```

Note: "myapp" is your service id.

Checkout this [Github implementation](https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-sandbox/tree/master/spring-cloud-sandbox-sample-frontend) for working example

Comment: Only need retry for feign.RetryableException.class and only for external-service feign client. My application contains multiple feign clients. for ribbon settings can we specify the specific feign client and exception class?

Comment: For such specific case, you need to go for FeignConfig and attached it to you FeignClient class and perform the logic

Answer (score 1):

This is my config. Test OK in spring boot 2.2.0.RELEASE
spring cloud Hoxton.M3.

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
MY-SPRING-API.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=2
MY-SPRING-API.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=2
MY-SPRING-API.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
MY-SPRING-API.ribbon.retryableStatusCodes=404,500

feign.client.config.PythonPatentClient.connectTimeout=500
feign.client.config.PythonPatentClient.readTimeout=500

hystrix.command.PythonPatentClient#timeTest(String).execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

java code is :

```
@FeignClient(name = "MY-SPRING-API",configuration = {PythonPatentConfig.class},fallbackFactory = FallBack.class)
public interface PythonPatentClient 
@RequestLine("GET /test?q={q}")
    void timeTest(@Param("appNo") String q);
```

Controller is :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public Object test() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("========important print enter test========");
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10L);
```

pom.xml additon add:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

optional:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>

@EnableRetry
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication
```

this is document :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#retrying-failed-requests

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/

Answer (score 0):

Adding this if it can help someone. I was getting connection reset using feign, as some unknown process was running on that port.
Try changing the port. [Refer this to find the process running on a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387451/how-can-i-kill-whatever-process-is-using-port-8080-so-that-i-can-vagrant-up/24388281)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that by creating a wrapper on top of ServiceClient

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceClient {

@Autowired
ServiceFeignClient serviceFeignClient;

@Retryable(value = { ClientReprocessException.class }, maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${retryMaxAttempts}}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${retryDelayTime}}"))

public void addPayment( AddPaymentRequest addPaymentRequest){
    return serviceFeignClient.addPayment(addPaymentRequest);
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a blog post about using Spring Retry with Feign Client methods. You may consider checking the [Post](https://engineering.getmidas.com/using-spring-retryable-with-feign-client-methods-9f77e509ad55). All steps have been explained in the post.