# Spring Cloud: Retry on failed Feign Client Request Before Fall Back

Tags: java, spring, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, spring-retry

Currently studying the integration of Feign and Spring Retry after reading this [article](http://ryanjbaxter.com/cloud/spring%20cloud/spring/2017/03/15/retrying-http-requests-in-spring-cloud-netflix.html) but unfortunately declaring the following on my application.yml file

```
sample:
 ribbon:
  MaxAutoRetries: 2
  ReadTimeout: 2000
  OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
```

The failed request was never retried but when I tried the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151448/feign-client-and-spring-retry). I created this configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class FeigConfig {

  @Bean
  public Retryer retryer() {
    return new Retryer.Default(1000L, 1000L, 3);
  }

  @Bean
  public Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return Logger.Level.BASIC;
  }
}
```

It suddenly works. Right now I just want to know

1) Why does the configuration on the application.yml doesn't work or is there something that I miss during the set-up but when I created the configuration class it seems ok.

2) In the event of retrying the request, is it possible to finish all of the retry calls before calling the fall back method.

Comment: Which version of spring cloud are you using ?

Comment: @yongsung.yoon currently using Camden.SR6

Comment: did you put spring-retry as a dependency ? From Camden.SR6 it's optional dependency. So you should put it explicitly.